# Surinder Singh route

Tags: uk-visa, uk-citizens, surinder-singh, non-citizens

I am British living in the UK. My husband is a non-EU citizen living in Germany with 3 year resident permit. I want to know the exact way for the Surinder Singh route. I’ve just recently found about this. I am planning to go and live with him from February to October and that’s when I need to return back to my studies in the UK. I wish he can come to the UK and support me here while I’m continuing my master's degree.

Do either of us have to work in Germany and provide money for both? To go the Surinder Singh route?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh

Answer (score 1):

From the link given by @mkennedy in comments you will need to integrate and make Germany the centre of your lives, at least for a while.

You really should consider getting expert legal advice which, while costly, may avoid the greater expense of temporarily relocating abroad being wasted if the Singh route fails through lack of planning on your part.