# Explain the Surinder Singh route

Tags: uk-citizens, refugees, surinder-singh

If I live with my husband in an EU country for a minimum of 3 months, and I am a British citizen, are we required to work there and not be on benefits?

I'm trying to understand how the Surinder Singh route would apply to me and my husband. He is a non-EU national living in Germany on a 3-year residence permit as a refugee.

Comment: For background, this user's husband is a non EU national living in Germany on 3 year residence permit as a refugee.

Comment: @user16259 yes that’s right

Comment: Sorry I really don’t understand how this app works. Am just posting questions hoping someone will help me. I feel overwhelmed with all this. I extended my MSc studies so that I can live with my husband in Germany as I was away from him for 1 year and half. Than I heard about the surinder route which is a bonus as I am already planning to go and live there with him till September when I return to my studies.

Comment: Lucia, set up an account at [Expatriates.SE], and link it to your account here if you like.  Then ask your question there, or flag this question for a moderator's attention and ask for it to be migrated there.

Comment: @phoog thank you but how do I set an account there. I flagged the question I don’t knw if I did this right but I’ll wait to see what happens :)

Comment: @Lucia To join [expatriates.se], make sure you're logged in here. Go to Expatriates and there should be a blue button at the top right that says, "Join this community".

Comment: On another note are you sure your husband isn't using you to his benefit and trying to gain residency in UK/EU. There have been multiple cases like this.

Comment: No because he doesn’t want to come to the uk because all his family is there. But I don’t want to live in Germany so Im trying to convince him. It will be better for him to stay in germany because he has the refugee status and 3 yrs resident permit. His learning the language and earning benefits whereas in the uk he can’t get all that. If he does stay in the uk with me he needs to work and learn English etc.

Comment: @mkennedy there no blue button there’s only questions

Comment: @Dumbcoder may still be correct. If your husband already speaks English it will be to his advantage to have the right to work in the UK rather than claim benefits in Germany (at least until his German is good enough to get a skilled job there)

Comment: @user16259 there will be a lot of jobs for him in the uk. But what’s the best way for him to come to the uk and live with me while I complete my studies here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surinder Singh route](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13017/surinder-singh-route)

Answer (score 2):

This is the UK government webpage

https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh

As neither of you can speak German and you are apparently planning to only pause your studies in the UK I suspect you will fail the requirement to make Germany the centre of your lives.

Your main problem might really be that, as you said, he doesn't want to move to UK.

Comment: Why? I can extend my studies for years if I want to. As a native English speaker I can find a job in Germany. But I’ve heard different different thing regarding the surinder route like it says In the gov website that I can proof Iam self sufficient but people in Germany stated no one of us have to work

Comment: This is getting a bit confusing with two parallel questions from the same op. Moderators, can you merge them?

Comment: Taking your questions as a whole, it seems like you are planning to make a short stay in Germany and put your masters course on pause. To repeat what I said elsewhere: you should get professional advice because you risk going to a lot of trouble moving to Germany and then still having your application rejected by the UK.

Comment: do you know of a good solicitor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. If you don't get any recommendations you could start with this link http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/